# How to upload an image using a file input and php

Tags: php, file-upload

I am trying to upload image by the below code and i am getting the file name from input file field.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['requestsubmit']))
{
$field_values_array1 = $_REQUEST['name'];
$field_values_array2 = $_REQUEST['address'];
$field_values_array3 = $_REQUEST['image'];

foreach($field_values_array1 as $k=>$value1){}
foreach($field_values_array2 as $k=>$value2){}
foreach($field_values_array3 as $k=>$value3){

$insert ="INSERT INTO `infotown_house`.`test` (`id`, `userName`, `cat`, `image`) VALUES (NULL, '".$field_values_array1[$k]."', '".$field_values_array2[$k]."', '".$field_values_array3[$k]."')";

mysql_query($insert);
```

Comment: error/ desired situation / pls clarify and write exactly the part we can help with.

Comment: @baboizk: thing is I dnt know how to upload image by this but when I tried "$field_values_array3 = $_FILES['image'];" i didn't get anythng but when i used "$field_values_array3 = $_REQUEST['image'];" I m getting the file name. dont know how to upload image by this code. Plzz hlp

Comment: Have you added `enctype="multi..."` to form?

Comment: @Sougata: No but I have added now and I am getting some value like this  "Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => anitree.gif ) [type] => Array ( [0] => image/gif ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => E:\wamp\tmp\phpE737.tmp ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 317510 ) )"

Comment: I am sure you can do the rest now. :)

Comment: Search in google 'php file upload example'. tons of example are there. `https://goo.gl/swynWN`

Comment: @Sougata: thats I want How to upload image by this code? plzzz hlp

Comment: Do **GOOGLE**. **How to upload files with PHP**.

Comment: @Sougata: here i am tryng bt not wrkng: "$field_values_array3 = $_FILES['image'];
 
  $field_values_array4=time('u').$field_values_array3['name'];
     $field_values_array5=$field_values_array3['tmp_name'];
     $field_values_array6="../img/products/".$field_values_array4;
     move_uploaded_file($field_values_array5,$field_values_array6);"

Answer (score -1):

Suggestion #1: don't use $_REQUEST >>> use $_FILE

Suggestion #2: don't use mysql_* >>> use mysqli_*

Suggestion #3: your foreach loop is shitty - is there some code missing?

Suggestion #4: don't use queries within loops if it is not neccessary

Suggestion #5: 'id' is not neccessary to be set, if it is auto increment

Suggestion #6: You need to save the uploaded Image. you can use move_uploaded_file() to do it

Comment: **Suggestions** not **Answers**. :)

Comment: I think suggestion #6 is the answer. But nitul didnt ask a specific question.